# Hosted Front-end Unable to Access Hosted Backend, but Local Front-end is Able to Access Hosted Back-end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I have created a MERN chat-app and am facing a few problems. Everything works fine, locally. The problems only start when I host my project, which are as follows:
I am unable to access the hosted backend from my hosted frontend.
The weird part is that **if I am running the frontend locally (and calling the hosted backend), it works fine** (except for the socket.io part, which obviously can only be accessed with permission). When I use a proxy, I get a 404 error, and when I don't, I get a cors error. I also tried installing the cors package, but that again gave a 404 error. Please tell me where am I messing up. Thanks in advance!

Back-end

https://chatter-backend-90rs.onrender.com

https://github.com/DenzilJD/chatter-backend

Front-end

https://chatterdjd.netlify.app/

https://github.com/DenzilJD/chatter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your signup `API` hitting this URL :**

[image]

**Your signup `API` should this URL :**
[image]

Comment: Hi. I have used a proxy to solve that issue. It is working for postman and even in a local frontend environment (calling hosted backend APIs), but not for the hosted frontend.

Comment: I try to singup in your app and see this api is calling which is wrong url. try to add right url that i give you in postman screenshot

Comment: Yes, I had tried that too. That is giving cors error. Also, I don't think my URL is wrong. Please check the proxy in my package.json of my frontend.

Comment: You did't make any constant file for deployed backed URL ? 
**const backendURL = https://chatter-backend-90rs.onrender.com/**
`const { data } = await axios.get(`${backendURL}/api/user/?search=${temp}`, config);
`

Comment: try above code in your project

Comment: This was giving cors error. Once I installed the cors package to fix the issue, it gives 404 error.

Comment: I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a working solution. The first thing is that 'proxy' in the package.json of the front-end only works for local environments. So I had to put in the API base link within the fetch requests.

After resolving this issue, I started facing the cors error, which I fixed by installing the cors package, and creating an exception for my front-end. A minor detail that is worth noting is that **abc.com** and **abc.com/** are considered different, which was why my cors error persisted. After I fixed this issue, my app was working as expected!

Edit: Thanks for the help @Jayesh Cholker.